# Aws-sdk s3 upload CORS error cause by CacheControl Option

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors, aws-sdk, cache-control

My code is looks like this and when

```
import { FileUpload } from "../types/scalars/Upload.scalar";

 new S3.ManagedUpload({
        params: {
            ACL: "public-read",
            Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKETNAME || "",
            Body: upload.createReadStream(),
            Key: filename || upload.filename,
            CacheControl: "max-age=604800,public,immutable",
        },
        // tags,
    }).promise();
```

If I upload this with the CacheControl option, upload works fine.

But when I load it on the client side I get a CORS error.

**If I remove CachControl, obviously the CORS error doesn't come up.**

My Bucket has CORS-Policy like this

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "POST"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

Headers with CacheControl Param

[image]

Headers without CachControl Param

[image]

With CacheControl param,
My Allow headers are gone. Why is that?

I found some documents in here https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem.
Did you set bucket policy in Amazon S3 actions?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-with-s3-actions.html

It worked by setting policy in my project.

And you can check if settings works by using curl.
The below command is check if POST request can access to a bucket.

```bash
curl -i https://your-bucket-name.s3.your-bucket-region.amazonaws.com/index.html -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: POST" -X OPTIONS -H "Origin: http://localhost:3000"
```

Check this link out.
https://aws.amazon.com/jp/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-configure-cors/